# How To Share Single Class Between Multiple Classes

Tags: python

What is the best way to share a class `A` between two or more other classes `B` and `C`.

For example in file `a.py`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('filename', 'a')

    def __del__(self):
        self.file.close()

    def write(self, text):
        print(text, file=self.file)
```

which is used for logging results. For obvious reasons I only want to load the file a single time and have all other classes access this single class to write to the files.

Then there is class `B` in file `b.py`:

```
 from a import A

 class B(object):

     def __init__(self):
          self.A = a.A()
```

Then there is class `C` in file `c.py`:

```
 from a import A

 class C(object):

     def __init__(self):
          self.A = a.A()
```

The problem is that it seems that if I'm using inheritance it would not work well if there are multiple files of this sort than need to be included in multiple other classes. What is the best practice for including a general helper class in all other classes, while only loading it a single time?

Comment: Did you mean "how to use the same _instance_"? How about creating a single instance `the_a = A()` in module `a` itself and then use that in both `b` and `c`?

Comment: You might want to look into how [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) does this; *"Note that Loggers are never instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function `logging.getLogger(name)`. Multiple calls to `getLogger()` with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object."*

Comment: You could consider passing the instance of your "A" class in the constructor of your "B" and "C" classes. Also, you could check out the "borg design pattern". Depending on how you want to expand on this in the future, it could be worth looking into. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/

Comment: @tobias_k: But wouldn't importing the module in both B and C cause to different instances of the class to be generated?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: This is just a dummy example, I have other instances such as NLP classes which are 100% custom.

Comment: @user2694306 so? The idea is still the same; instantiate once, then access by some unique ID.